# Recursion algorithm Stops running after finding the first Leaf node

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I do apology in advance if there are many variables in the following code sample that their "types" is not clear to you, it is a big library, I just can't put all of that in here, so think of it at high-level, and the name of the variables is kind of helpful too...

Problem: A "concept" can have many "relations". Each of those relations can also have many concepts, For example like a father and child, a father has many children, a child may itsself be a father and has more children ,etc...
So I want to pass the root father and get all the hierarchy and write it to a file ...

The high-level code I am using is this, THE PROBLEM IS THAT it Crashes by a Null exception when it gets the child that has no more children. So its object is null in this line:

```
oUCMRConceptReltn = moTargetConceptList.ConceptReltns.get_ItemByIndex(i, false);
```

So I thought well let's put a not null check around it, yeah fixes the crash BUT after it sees the first leafe, it doesn't go further and algorithm stops. 
So Something is wrong with the way I am calling recursion, but can't figure it out.

```
private void MyLoadMethod(string sConceptCKI)
{
    UCMRConceptLib.UCMRConceptLoadQual oUCMRConceptLoadQual = new UCMRConceptLib.UCMRConceptLoadQual();

    //Fill out UCMRConceptLoadQual object to get new list of related concepts
    moTargetConceptList.Load(oUCMRConceptLoadQual;

    // WHEN IT IS ZERO, THERE ARE NO MORE CHILDREN.
    int numberofKids = moTargetConceptList.ConceptReltns.Count();
    if (numberofKids == 0)
        return ;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberofKids; i++)
    {
        oUCMRConceptReltn = moTargetConceptList.ConceptReltns.get_ItemByIndex(i, false);

            //Get the concept linked to the relation concept
            if (oUCMRConceptReltn.SourceCKI == sConceptCKI)
            {
                oConcept = moTargetConceptList.ItemByKeyConceptCKI(oUCMRConceptReltn.TargetCKI, false);
            }
            else
            {
                oConcept = moTargetConceptList.ItemByKeyConceptCKI(oUCMRConceptReltn.SourceCKI, false);
            }

            //write its name to the file...now recursion: go and find its children.
            builder.AppendLine("\t" + oConcept.PrimaryCTerm.SourceString);
            MyLoadMethod(oConcept.ConceptCKI);
    }
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a side note, the check for number of kids being 0 is redundant, because you're never going to enter the loop.

The algorithm looks okay for what you want to do.  You don't need to return anything in this case because your algorithm uses a side effect (the appendLine) to give your output.

I don't know C#, but it looks to me as if you're using some variables that are not local to the function, like `oUCMRConceptReltn` and `oConcept`.  If they're not local to the function, different recursive invocations can change those values in unexpected ways.  Recursive functions should almost never write to a variable outside its own scope.

Comment: Thanks, good points... Yes that kids 0 was redundant. I removed it now.. .. This point that you mentioned solved a huge problem in my code, yeah one of the variables was initialized OUTSIDE of this method...

Answer (score 1):

Most indexes in c style languages are 0 based. So don't loop through 1 to numberofKids, loop 0 to numberofKids-1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberofKids; i++)
```

Comment: yeah, but that one is not the issue..this code once been in VB 6.0 and later been uplifted to C#, so that weird indexing is because of that..but that's not the problem i have.

Comment: Ok, well I'll leave it up here to stop others suggesting the same.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'uplifted to c#'...but the c style indexing that Weston mentions seems to be the problem to me too...what type is the .ConceptReltns property?

Comment: Guys! Just forget about Index issue...that's not the problem.
Now a question: The method I have declared is "void" for its return type...shouldn't all recursive methods return some sort of value that can be used later in recursion? I guess that's one of the problems ..not sure tho..what do you think?

Comment: "My car won't start."  
"Your car doesn't have an engine."  
"That's not the problem!  My car is blue.  Do you think that could be the problem?"

Comment: @BDotA not nessasarily, you appear to be accessing a member called `builder`. A recursive function can have a void return type and still have a use if it acts apon an argument, or a global (including private members, public statics, UI or files etc). The answer might be to step through this and see what's wrong. Maybe use `Debug.WriteLine` and view output in the console. No one can do this for you as it's not a [compileable example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @BDotA Anything that's tail-recursive is a good candidate for not having a return type since calculations are passed on through the parameters and not blown up on the call stack.